# Unable to Serialize HTML Form using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hello there i am a newbie in ASP.NET development.I am unable to get the correct serialize form using Jquery.[image: you can see that asp hidden fields is attached to my serialize string]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button2").click(function () {
            var form = $("#form1").serialize();
            alert(form);

        });
    });
   </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button2" Text="submit" />
    <div>

   </div>
  </form>
  </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: @JasonP i was expecting key value pairs and then i wanted to recieve them in FormCollection but it is giving me error that "unable to parse _VIEWSTATE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form serialization appears to be working correctly. It serializes the form into a URL format of `name=value` pairs. For example `name=First%20Last&age=27`.

Because you're using ASP.NET forms they have a hidden `__VIEWSTATE` field. That's why you're seeing `__VIEWSTATE=SC20935uo236h2oth3li3h...`. You shouldn't need to submit the viewstate because that's an ASP.NET-specific mechanism for tracking what state the forms are in.

You can exclude the `__VIEWSTATE` field from the serialization by using JQuery to select all inputs *except* `__VIEWSTATE`.

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function() {
    var serializedFields = $('input[name!=__VIEWSTATE]', this).serialize();
    console.log(serializedFields);
});
```

Open your browser's developer console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on windows) to see the `console.log()` messages (this is far better than using alerts).

This works by listening for the form's `submit` event, then querying for all fields *except* `__VIEWSTATE`. Because we're inside the form submit event, `this` refers to the form, so we pass that as the context for our selector, hence the `$('...', this)`.

Comment: can we also ommit VIEWSTATEGENERATOR like this?

Comment: Yes, just use a comma in your selector to do multiple attribute checks. '[...],[...]'

Comment: Almost. You shouldn't close the quotes around the comma. `'input[name!=__VIEW‌​STATEGENERATOR],inp‌​ut[name!=__VIEWSTATE]'‌​`